# Python - MySql - Compare fields and change

Tags: python, html, mysql, web-scraping

Morning Folks.

I am scraping some data from a local Property Company, data is then put into a local mysql DB. What I would like to do is compare one field (closing_date) to current date. Once closing_date is now or has passed either change the closing_date to 0000-00-00 or Null.

I plan at some point to display the data on a webpage local to me only, is the above the best way to do what I want within Python or would it be best achieved when displaying the data instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime


web_link_list = []


class House:
    def __init__(self, address, advert, postcode, area, prop_type, opening_date, closing_date, bedrooms, weblink):
    self.address = address
    self.advert = advert
    self.postcode = postcode
    self.area = area
    self.prop_type = prop_type
    self.opening_date = opening_date
    self.closing_date = closing_date
    self.bedrooms = bedrooms
    self.weblink = weblink

def insert_sql(self):
    my_db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                    user='test1',
                                    password='testpass',
                                    database='Houses')

    my_cursor = my_db.cursor()

    sql = "insert ignore into tb1 (address, advert, postcode, area, property_type, opening_date, closing_date, bedrooms, weblink) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = (self.address, self.advert, self.postcode, self.area, self.prop_type, self.opening_date, self.closing_date, self.bedrooms, self.weblink)
    my_cursor.execute(sql, val)
    my_db.commit()
    print(my_cursor.lastrowid, " Inserted")


def get_links():

    url = 'https://angushomefinder.homeconnections.org.uk/my-cbl/property-search'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'blue-btn'}, href=True):
        web_link_list.append('https://angushomefinder.homeconnections.org.uk' + item['href'])


def get_house():
    for item in web_link_list:
        page = requests.get(item)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        result = soup.find('table', class_="tableproperty")

        new_house = House(soup.find('address', {'class': 'address-box'}).text.title(),
                      result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Advert'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Advert'}) else None).text,
                      result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Post code'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Post code'}) else None).text,
                      result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Area'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Area'}) else None).text.title(),
                      result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Property type'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Property type'}) else None).text.title(),
                      datetime.strptime(result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Opening date'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Opening date'}) else None).text, '%d/%m/%Y'),
                      datetime.strptime(result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Closing date'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Closing date'}) else None).text, '%d/%m/%Y'),
                      result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Bedrooms'} if result.find('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Bedrooms'}) else None).text,
                      item)
    House.insert_sql(new_house)


get_links()
get_house()
```

Comment: *What I would like to do is compare one field (opening_date) to another field (closing_date). Once closing_date is => 8 days then either change the closing_date to 0000-00-00 or Null.* Do you want to adjust the value diring row insertion or you want to process existing rows? Or you want not to alter the data and simply adjust the value to be shown during data retrieving?

Comment: I think the best way would be to do it AFTER insertion, so process existing rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> process existing rows. – pr0xibus

If you want to modify the values in the rows where the distance between the values is 8 days or more then

```
UPDATE table_name
SET closing_date = NULL
WHERE DATEDIFF(closing_date, opening_date) >= 8
-- AND closing_date IS NOT NULL
```

If I understand your criteria incorrectly then adjust the condition (use correct comparing operator).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, BUT I realised I asked the wrong question, just as I was doing your query.

I have updated my question on the original post, what I would now like is compare Closing_date with current date rather than 7 days... apologies this was my fault not working through the logic

Comment: @pr0xibus What a problem? `WHERE DATEDIFF(closing_date, CURRENT_DATE) >= 7`

Comment: Yup now that is exactly what I was looking for

update tb1 set closing_date = NULL where datediff(closing_date, NOW()) >= 7 and closing_date is not null;